# Как сделать Input disabled? React + Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, forms, reactjs

На форме есть два инпута. 
Как в реакте сделать так, чтобы начиная вводить в одном Input-e, второй стал disabled
Использую react-bootstrap и компонент FormControl для инпутов отсюда
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-props-form-control

то есть у меня два компонента FormGroup, внутри каждого  FormControl.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, как-то так:

```js
'use strict';

var Inputs = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
       firstSet: false,
       secondSet: false
        };
    },
    
    onCheckRuleClick: function(e) {
        this.setState({agreeNotChecked: !this.state.agreeNotChecked});
    },
    
 fieldChange: function(fieldName, e) {
        if (e.target.value.trim().length > 0) {
            this.setState({[''+fieldName]:true})
        } else {
            this.setState({[''+fieldName]:false})
        }
    },
    
    render: function() {
        var secondSet = this.state.secondSet,
         firstSet = this.state.firstSet;
            
        return (
            <form className='add cf'>
   
   <input
                    type='text'
                    className='first'
                    onChange={this.fieldChange.bind(this, 'secondSet')}
                    placeholder='Первый'
     disabled={firstSet}
                />
                
    <input
                    type='text'
                    className='second'
                    onChange={this.fieldChange.bind(this, 'firstSet')}
                    placeholder='Второй'
     disabled={secondSet}
                />
                
            </form>
        );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log('render');
        return (
            <div className='app'>
                <Inputs />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test on React</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root">Привет, я #root</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Функция `onCheckRuleClick` не нужна, просто не доглядел, когда удалял лишнее.